# Converting a Flex custom component to a module

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, module, flex3

How to take an existing custom component in Flex and convert it into a module?

EDIT: What should be done in the mxml where this custom component is used? Should it be replaced with a  to load the module? If yes, how to deal with code that uses instances of the components?

Answer (score 1):

Change the root mxml tag to `<mx:Module...` then in the properties of the project click on the "Flex Modules" button and add it in there.

Edit: This is assuming your modules are in the same project. I prefer to create new projects per module as it makes development easier with multiple developers. So what I do is create a new project, change the root to `<mx:Module...`, in the properties of the module project I disable it from creating the html wrapper, then in my main project I just load up the module swf's based on what menu item was clicked

Comment: The problem with having a separate project, is that you'll have to worry about relative paths and making sure everything is compiling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to place a ModuleLoader in place of the custom component like

```
<mx:ModuleLoader id="moduleLoader" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

And load the Module using the url.

```
moduleLoader.unloadModule();
```

`moduleLoader.url = "path\to\module.swf"; 
moduleLoader.loadModule();`

You can keep the above code in a function and load modules.

If your module will be used in the same project only, you can create a new MXML Module that can be optimized for the project from FlexBuilder